# How to have media query widths apply to preset bootstrap xs sm md lg column classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

For bootstrap, there are existing width cutoffs built into the classes themselves (e.g. col-xs-3, col-sm-8, col-md-10, col-lg-1). These classes are already preset to cutoff at 768m 992, and 1024px.

If you define your own cutoff points via media queries, how do you ensure the preset classes like `col-xs-3` are indeed cutting off at the cutoffs you specified via media queries like so?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 600px) { 
  //your code stuff
}

@media only screen and (min-width:600px) and (max-width: 900px) { 
  //your code stuff         
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px)  { 
  //your code stuff
}
```

How do you get these cutoff points defined in media queries to actually correspond to col-xs, sm md lg, etc? Or is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: You have to make a custom build: [Customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system)

Comment: I'd like to keep bootstrap vanilla, and layer on my custom stuff.
Can I not simply define custom variables lower in my style sheets in order to override the variable values?
How do you do a custom build using rails gems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These values (break points) are set by the  `$screen-sm-min`, `$screen-md-min` and `$screen-lg-min` variables in Bootstrap's `variables.less` file.

When changing your break point you also have to change the container widths.
I suggest you use the following formula to do that:

```
$container-*:           floor( ( $screen-* - $grid-gutter-width ) / $grid-columns ) * $grid-columns + $grid-gutter-width;
```

See also: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15623#issuecomment-96294396

And finally you should possible also take the into account. Which has been declared in the `variables.less` file too, as follows:

```
//** Point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed.
$grid-float-breakpoint:     $screen-sm-min !default;
```

> How do you do a custom build using rails gems?

See also https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails:

> In your Gemfile you need to add the bootstrap-sass gem, and ensure that the >sass-rails gem is present - it is added to new Rails applications by default.

And then: Import Bootstrap styles in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`:

```
// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
$screen-sm-min: 300px;
$container-sm: floor( ( $screen-sm - $grid-gutter-width ) / $grid-columns ) * $grid-columns + $grid-gutter-width;
$screen-md-min: 600px;
$container-md: floor( ( $screen-md - $grid-gutter-width ) / $grid-columns ) * $grid-columns + $grid-gutter-width;
$screen-lg-min: 900px;
$container-lg: floor( ( $screen-lg - $grid-gutter-width ) / $grid-columns ) * $grid-columns + $grid-gutter-width;

@import "bootstrap";
```

Bootstrap's code has been build with a mobile first approach. The `xs` grid is the default and does not require any media query at all. Then the `sm` grid follows for screen width larger than `$screen-sm-min` and so on. You do not have to set a `max-width` media query.